# how to make my php page reload each 2 minutes using javascript?

Tags: php, settimeout

Every  two minutes i want to check whether i received some message so want to reload my page every 2 minutes how to reload my php page using javascript

Comment: May I ask why? usually you just want to refresh a section of the page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<body onload="setInterval('window.location.reload()', 120000);">
```

Comment: simple and effective :)

Answer (score 3):

Why are you sticking on javascript. You can do this without Javascript too.
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://path/to/the/page" />`

Comment: Hi 
Its working good is there any advantage of using this in meta tag instead of using in javascript

Comment: If the user has javascript disabled this will continue to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    location.reload()
}, 120000);
```

Though I think there could possibly be a fancier way of doing this, this is just what I know though.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into doing it with ajax. Look at the jQuery library, or any of the JavaScript libraries.

http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found out which is also javascript proof.

This code goes in between the HEAD tags.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">
```

The above code reloads the page every 15 seconds. Change 15 to the desired value as required. For eg; 300 for a page to reload every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="n">
```

What if your client doesn't have javascript e.g feature phone browsers?
Put that in the head folder of your HTML header. n is the number of seconds for the refresh intervals.