# Redirecting a page doesn't work unless I refresh it first

Tags: php, http, redirect, refresh

I am trying to redirect a page to the homepage after 2 minutes

I have tried using

```
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="120;url=http://mysite.com/index.php">
```

and

```
 <!--
 window.setTimeout('window.location="http://mysite.com/index.php"; ',1200000);
 // -->
```

Both methods work if I refresh the page - if I don't refresh the page, nothing happens

Help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     <!--
     window.setTimeout('window.location="mysite.com/index.php"; ',2000);
     // -->
 </script>
        <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="120;url=http://mysite.com/index.php">  
    <title>Patrol Report</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    table { width:100%; }
    table caption { text-align:left;  }
    table thead th { text-align:left; border-bottom-width:1px; border-top-width:1px; }
    table th, td { text-align:left; padding:6px;} 

    </style>
</head> 

<body>
```

index.php calls list.php

```
src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Mobile Patrol Report</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=outward">Outward Housing Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=newlon">Newlon Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=octavia">Octavia Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=poplar">Poplar Harca Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=stadium">Stadium Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=wessex">First Wessex Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=christian">Christian Housing Exemptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?>list.php?type=isha">ISHA Exemptions</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&COPY W8S.co.uk</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are a nubder of sql statements that define the data shown

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your full code?  I don't see any reason for this not working other than headers being sent before your Refresh request.

Comment: I tried your code on my virtual server and it worked properly, how are you calling upon this webpage?

Comment: I've added the index page - there are sql statements called by each menu item

Comment: I would try removing the code <?php echo HTDOCS_URL; ?> in each href, I don't know the purpose of this and don't know the function

Answer (score 0):

use this piece of code instead of your body tag:

```
<body onload="setInterval('window.location=http://mysite.com/index.php', 120000);">
```

refer to [how to make my php page reload each 2 minutes using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058796/how-to-make-my-php-page-reload-each-2-minutes-using-javascript) that answered by [Babiker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98204/babiker).

Or If you want to use PHP for this, here you go:
[How to redirect to another page after 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866572/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-after-5-minutes)
 like this : `<?php header("Refresh: 120; URL=http://mysite.com/index.php"); ?>`

Comment: Hi - I don't want to reload the page, I want to direct the user to a new page

Comment: Hi - as i mentioned it, user will redirect to an specific URL, you can specify your custom address in the URL section.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `ob_start();` at the beginning after you start the session.